# Is there any registry key to check all outlook inactive Addins (Not Disabled)

Tags: outlook, registry, outlook-addin

We know in outlook there are three states of a AddIn  Active , Inactive , Disabled.
 **

- My question is how we can determine if a AddIn is in Inactive state
  using some registry Keys

** or any other method to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **LoadBehavior** windows registry key under the {Root}\Software\Microsoft\Office{application name}\Addins{add-in ID} key contains a bitwise combination of values that specify the run time behavior of the add-in. The lowest order bit (values 0 and 1) indicates whether the add-in is currently unloaded or loaded. Other bits indicate when the application attempts to load the add-in. See [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) for more information.

Be aware, Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

You can read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

Comment: Is it possible that LoadBehavior is 3 and AddIn is still inactive ??

Comment: @theJoker I do think it's possible as i have a problem like this. I have an console app that tracks the registry value of my installed add-in. I can confirm it was 3 but shows as disabled by outllook, I wanted to know also where in registry is the value that indicates that the add-in was disabled by outlook itself